# Identify font substitution in PowerPoint 2010

Tags: fonts, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

How do I identify font substitution in PowerPoint 2010? In my computer I have several fonts. I get PowerPoint files from my friends, and I would like to quickly check whether they have used any font that is not in my computer and font substitution has happened. Is there a way by which this can be quickly checked? Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### A) To see a list of all the fonts used in a presentation

1. Go to `File` tab / `Info`
2. In the right pane click the down arrow next to `Properties` and choose `Advanced Properties`:

   [image: 1]
3. Click on the `Contents` tab:

   [image: 2]

#### B) To check whether fonts used in a presentation are installed on your system or not

1. On the `Home` tab go to the `Editing` group
2. Click the down arrow next to `Replace` and choose `Replace Fonts`:

   [image: 3]
3. The upper of the two list boxes tells you what fonts the presentation uses, and a **?** next to any of the fonts indicates that the font isn't installed on your system

   [image: 4]